# Issue in trigger for count of records in look up relationship

Tags: apex, lookup, count

I have two custom obj, `Parent__c` and `Child__c` with a Lookup relationship between them.

I'm just trying to count the Child records via trigger, but I'm getting error when i create a new child record

> unexpected exception

```
trigger ConCount on Child__c (after insert) {
    Set <id> CHildIds = new set<id>();
    List<Child__c> ChildList = new List<Child__c>();
    List<Child__c> ListCon = new List<Child__c>();
    List<Parent__c> ParentList = new List <Parent__c>();
    List<Parent__c> ListParent = new List <Parent__c>();
    Map<id,integer> ConMap = new map <id,integer>();

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        for(Child__c Chil : Trigger.New){
            CHildIds.add(Chil.Parentlookup__c);}   
            ParentList = [select id, name from Parent__c where id IN :CHildIds];
            ChildList = [select id,name , Parentlookup__c from Child__c where Parentlookup__c IN :CHildIds];
                for(Parent__c P :ParentList){
                    Listcon.clear();
                        for(Child__c C : ChildList){
                            if(C.Parentlookup__c == P.id){
                                ListCon.add(C);
                                 ConMap.put(P.id,ListCon.size());
                             } 
                        }
                    }

                    if(ParentList.size()>0){
                        for(Parent__c Pa : ParentList){
                            if(ConMap.size()>0){
                                Pa.ContactsCount__c = ConMap.get(Pa.id);
                                ListParent.add(Pa);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(ListParent.size()>0)
                        update ListParent;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of child records that exist under the parent  record? If so, are you aware of [relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)?

Comment: Relationship queries won't work if there is too much childs !
What the exact error message you got ? By the way, if every child has a parent record associated, you should use master detail instead of lookup. It'll allow you to use standard feature (roll-up summary field) instead of developping !

Comment: @MickaelMaisel QueryExcpetion will only be hit dependent on how the developer decides to access the retrieved child records.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to achieve this, Hopefully (this will only work on small amount of querying/sub-querying data it should not be exceed the limit.)

```
trigger triggercount on Contact (after insert) {
if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
    List<Account> accListToBeUpdate = new List<Account>();
    set<Id> accountIds = new set<Id>();
    for(Contact c: trigger.new){
        accountIds.add(c.AccountId); //set of account related to added contacts
    }  
    //Retrieving accounts and sub-querying related contacts to each account.
    List<Account> acclist = [select id,Count_Contacts__c, (select id from contacts) from Account where id IN: accountIds];
    for(Account a: acclist){
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.id = a.id;
        acc.Count_Contacts__c = a.contacts.size(); //contacts.size will give size of related contacts on account
        accListToBeUpdate.add(acc);
    }
    update accListToBeUpdate; //updating accounts
}}
```

Comment: Be very careful when using *acc.Count_Contacts__c = a.contacts.size();* within a for each loop containing a subquery. If the child records are greater than 200 you will receive a QueryException. You should iterate through each child record and update a variable to get your count.

Comment: An answer that only has code isn't as useful as it could be. My philosophy here is that if someone can simply copy/paste an answer, then the person asking the question has learned nothing. This answer would be improved if you would include additional explanation of how it works, and how it's different than what the question asker already has. Of the two answers on this question, this is by far the better approach. I'll hold my upvote until additional explanation (of this answer) is given.

Comment: @DerekF I have commented my code, please review and if any issue let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this referring Account is Parent and Address is child record. please replace Account as Parent and Address as child in my below code snippet : -

for this below code I have taken Account as Parent object and Address as chils object..please find my code comment below : -

```
trigger countAddressinAccount on Address__c (after Insert) {
    List<Id> lst_ParentId = new List<Id>();//list of Account which new Address records will be created.
    List <AggregateResult> aggrs = new List<AggregateResult>();// store the sum of child records  
    Map<Id,Integer> map_account_addree_count = new Map<Id,Integer>();// store the Account Id and the number of child records 
    List<Account> lst_account = new List<Account>();// Store the number of account which will be affected.
    List<Account> lst_account_update = new List<Account>();//Store the number of accounts which will be updated.

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){ 
        for(Address__c  add :Trigger.New){ 
            lst_ParentId.add(add.publish__Account__c);    //list of account added  for which child records will be created
        }    
    }

     if(!lst_ParentId.isEmpty() && lst_ParentId.size()>0){
     //Make a aggregate query to find out how may child records available for each account
        aggrs =[SELECT publish__Account__r.Id accountId, Count(id) total
                    FROM publish__Address__c where publish__Account__r.Id IN : lst_ParentId
                    GROUP BY ROLLUP(publish__Account__r.Id)];        
    }

    if(!aggrs.isEmpty() && aggrs.size()>0){
        for (AggregateResult ar : aggrs)  {            
            //System.debug('------'+ar.get('total'));
            if(ar.get('accountId')!=null){
                 System.debug('------'+ar.get('total'));
                 //make a map of account id and number of child records
                 map_account_addree_count.put((Id)ar.get('accountId'),Integer.valueOf(ar.get('total')));   
            }          
        }        
    }

    if(!aggrs.isEmpty() && aggrs.size()>0){
    //query the account fields which needs to be updated with the number of child records 
        lst_account = [Select Id,publish__Number_Of_Address__c from Account where id IN :map_account_addree_count.keyset()] ;
        if(!lst_account .isEmpty() && lst_account .size()>0){
            for(Account acc: lst_account ){
                acc.publish__Number_Of_Address__c = map_account_addree_count.get(acc.Id);//update the Account field
                lst_account_update.add(acc);// Added to the list
            }
        }        
    }

    if(!lst_account_update.isEmpty() && lst_account_update.size()>0){
        update lst_account_update;    //updated the account list
    }
}
```

it will work perfectly.

Comment: An answer that only has code isn't as useful as it could be (and is typically not very useful to anyone with a similar problem who visits this question in the future). My philosophy here is that if someone can simply copy/paste an answer, then the person asking the question has learned nothing. This answer would be improved if you would include additional explanation of how it works, and how it's different than what the question asker already has.

Comment: @Derek F, i have updated my answer. commented each line of the code.have a look and let me know in case of any issue.Above answer may be hit the limit but my answer is also Bulkified.

Answer (score 0):

Counting child records and populating the parent with the result is pretty simple and frequently asked. This below will handle cases when there are no more children and will keep the totals up to date....

After update is only added in case the Account Id Changes. Could probably throw in a static recursion flag to not run if the record is New unless you have updates on insert that could reparent the record

```
trigger countContacts on Contact(after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete){
    //Map of Accounts to update
    Map<Id, Account> acctsToUpdate = New Map<Id, Account>();

    //populate default value of 0 so if there are none remaining then the value is updated - If it is possible a contact will not have an account then you will need to skip those with no Account Id
    for (Contact c : trigger.isDelete ? trigger.old : trigger.new){
        acctsToUpdate.put(
                c.AccountId,
                New Account(
                     Id = c.AccountId,
                     Count_Field__c = 0
                )
        );

    }

    //Get count of Contacts related to Account alias AccountId as Id so the map assignment works
    Map<Id, AggregateResult> childCount = New Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
              [
                 Select 
                   Count(Id) cnt, 
                   AccountId Id 
                 From Contact 
                 Where AccountId In :acctsToUpdate.keySet()
                 Group By AccountId
              ]
    );
    //Populate the counts for those still having a value        
    for (Id key : childCount.keySet())
        acctsToUpdate.get(Key).Count_Field__c = (Integer) childCount.get(key).get('cnt');

    update acctsToUpdate.values(); //Should use database.update and handle errors or use false to let errors pass
}
```

I believe it is the most efficient way to do this adjust fields for your use case.

Most likely a duplicate of: [Contact Count Trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148585/contact-count-trigger/148653#148653) as the concept is the same

once in place a single data update on all contact records using batch apex or data loader will bring the counts up to date and from that point on they will be in sync